# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper "There was a p roblem running the initialization hooks" all of a sudden

Tags: python, django, bash, ubuntu

So my development environment really hasn't changed for a long time. I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows for about a year now. I just apply the regular updates with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Haven't had any issues until last week. When I would `workon env` and then start up Django, all of these Python errors related to encryption and hashing would come up. Don't really remember what they said, but apparently couldn't find something. I just ignored them because I am in the middle of a project and figured I'd address them later since it is just the dev server.

Anyway, I come in yesterday to work and all of a sudden I am getting:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.6 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I read a number of SO questions related to this. Basically they all suggested to uninstall `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, and `pip`. That is if doing `pip3 install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper` didn't work, which it didn't. Uninstalled, reinstalled, and left work yesterday with everything seeming to be running fine.

Came into work today and the problem is back so I am not sure how to fix it. I am running `Python 3.6.3` and `PIP3`. My `~/.bashrc` has the following with some additional lines that I have added to "fix" the issue:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6
export WORKON_HOME=/mnt/c/dev/.venvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRUTALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The latest error message is:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6 and that PATH is
set properly.
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.6 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

`Python 3.6.3` is in the `/usr/bin` and `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is in the `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. Not sure why it is looking in `/usr/local/bin/python3.6` as I don't see where this is specified.

Wish I knew what caused it to break all of a sudden. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, can't confirm 100%. But it *seems* like it *might* be related to the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update...? I did an `lxrun /uninstall /full` which failed as user and administrator. So did `lxrun /install` as both admin and user. It acted like it reinstalled, but when I opened Bash on Ubuntu on Windows it is basically telling me to go to the store. I guess it is now available through the store as opposed enabling Developer Mode and installing via `cmd.exe`. Also read something about moving your files out of the previous installation.

Comment: Also, had a fat update that took over an hour when I got into the office yesterday which leads me to believe it was the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. Can only speculate honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I will go ahead and answer this.

Apparently this is an issue related to the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. Using Ubuntu either with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (`lxrun`), or Ubuntu through the Windows Store (if you can get it to download), results in this error. From what I understand, the error is from using repos in the Linux environment to install such things as `virtualenv` or `npm install` on `/mnt/c` or any Windows drive. I guess an issue with symlinks between the two.

For me the environment broke with `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.19]`. This was on my work computer which basically shut me down for a few days until I figured out what was going on. My personal laptop was still under Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063] and ran fine. I had to have IT restore to a previous build and shut off Windows Updates until they fix the issue.

I had been running this setup since the beginning of the year with no issues installing `venvs` and `npm` repos in my project directories.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I managed to remove all those errors by adding

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)`

to .bashrc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).